# Encrypt excel-vba ADODB connection

Tags: excel, vba, ssl, encryption

I am in the process of creating some Excel reports and i am trying to encrypt my SQL connections. On server side i have everything setup properly and with Microsoft management studio i am able to establish a secure connection. However i cant find any solution for excel. I think i need something like `Encrypt = yes` or is this ADODB.Connection not supporting SSL ?

```
Private Function GetDataFromADO(ByVal Sel As String) As ADODB.Recordset

'Declare variables'
    Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset

    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

'Open Connection'
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & sqlServer & ";Database=" & _
        sqlDB & ";User ID=" & sqlUsername & ";Password=" & sqlPassword & ";"
    Dim s As String
    s = objMyConn.ConnectionString
    objMyConn.Open


'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyCmd.CommandText = Sel
    objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.Source = objMyCmd
    objMyRecordset.Open


Set GetDataFromADO = objMyRecordset
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know the connection to an SQL Server is not handled by Excel but by Windows (in terms of security, network, encryption, authentication, etc.). You cannot even set the Connection timeout in Excel / ADO. Well, you can of course use `ADODB.Connection.ConnectionTimeout = 5000`. But you might as well skip that line as it will have no impact. So, if I am not completely mistaken then you should focus on your SQL settings and make sure that it allows only encrypted connections: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191192.aspx Then you should be fine with `Trusted_Connection=yes`.

Answer (score 0):

The Force encryption option on my SQL Server did the trick.

Thanks Ralph :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to secure every connection to your SQL Server using SSL or TLS, then you should set the Force Encryption option to yes for the set of protocols on the server and also install a certificate generated by the Domain CA or a public CA. Setting Force Encryption to yes encrypts all connections with a self-signed certificate generated from the SQL Server. This leaves the possibility of a man in the middle attack open. The CA, or Certificate Authority, is the service or application used to attest to the identity of users, computers, and organizations as well as generate, manage and renew certificates.

Lets assume you are using a certificate generated by the domain CA. As long as your SQL Server, domain CA system and client system can communicate with each other, what should happen is that the client initiates a session with the SQL Server, which then responds with the request for a secure session and presents a certificate generated from the domain CA server to the client for validation. Then the client should validate the certificate in two ways, by verifying with the domain CA system that it is a valid certificate and by using the digital signature to verify that it has not been modified.

The basics of enabling SSL on your SQL Server are to import the certificate and private key into the certificate store of the service account running the database engine, then set the Force Encryption property to yes in the properties of the server protocols using SQL Server Configuration Manager and on the Certificate tab select the certificate generated from the domain CA or a public CA.

Comment: On my server is a website running as well. I have requested a certificate for my Website with Let's Encrypt and imported this one to the certificate store. So i am using the Lets Encrypt Certificate for my SQL Server as well. It looks like it is working. I am not using the Trusted_Connection=yes option. Only disadvantage: The lets Encrypt cert lasts for 6 month and only the original Cert in the Website Certificate store is renewed automatic

Comment: Sounds good. Definitely be proactive about replacing the SQL Server certificate before it expires. I've had that happen once in QA and it was critical.