# VBA Connection String to Connect SQL server with SSL Certificate

Tags: vba, ssl-certificate

I am using VBA connection string to connect SQL server in my VB script.It was running smoothly earlier.

Recently server team installed SSL certificate in that in which my macro is not running now and stating SSL Security error as like below snapshot.

[image: Error]

Can anyone help me to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance!!!

Regards,

Comment: Can you post your ConnectionString _(without credentials, obviously)_? There's also this helpful [collection of ConnectionStrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/).

Comment: cnSrc.Open "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source= " & cnServer & ";Initial Catalog=" & cndb & ";User Id=" & cnUser & ";Password=" & cnPwd & ";"

Comment: Also, have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200879/encrypt-excel-vba-adodb-connection). In your client code use the [Trusted_Connection=True;](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/trusted-connection/) flag.

Answer (score 0):

I would concatenate the values required for the connection string before you open it, instead of on `cnSrc.Open`.

I work with VBA and use ADO to query SQL server daily and I use the following format for my connection strings:

`Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=UserName;Password=Password;Data Source=SeverName;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName`

You can use the code below to test:

```
Private Sub TestConnection()

    Dim cnSrc As ADODB.Connection
    Dim CONNECTION_STRING As String
    Dim cnServer As String, cndb As String, cnUser As String, cnPwd As String

    cnServer = "SeverName"
    cndb = "DataBaseName"
    cnUser = "UserName"
    cnPwd = "Password"

    CONNECTION_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=" & cnUser & ";Password=" & cnPwd & ";" & _
                        "Data Source=" & cnServer & ";Initial Catalog=" & cndb

    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Set cnSrc = New ADODB.Connection
        cnSrc.Open CONNECTION_STRING

    'bit wise comparison to check the connection's state
    Debug.Assert (cnSrc.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen    'Debug.Assert pauses execution if false


CleanExit:
    'close the connection
    If Not cnSrc Is Nothing Then: If (cnSrc.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then cnSrc.Close
    Set cnSrc = Nothing
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    Resume CleanExit

End Sub
```